# how to set a radio button as checked in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have a list of options and one of them is selected. How would I test in Vuejs2 and set as checked the appropriate one. For example,
 wanting per watt set as `checked` below (https://jsfiddle.net/bsj1t2z9/2/)

html:

```html
    <div id='app'></div>
```

Vue app:

```html
    new Vue({
      el:"#app",
      template:`<div>
         saying hello
         <div>{{selected_unit}}</div>
         <div class="radio" v-for="pricingUnit in pricing_units">
           <label><input type="radio" name="pricing[unconfirmed_units]" >{{pricingUnit.display}}</label>
        </div>

      </div>
      `,
      data: {
        selected_unit:'per_watt',
        pricing_units: [
          {short:'per_watt', display:'Per Watt'},
          {short:'flat_rate', display:'Flate Rate'}
        ]
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vue.js docs have a good example of this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio

Here is a working version of your fiddle, remember to use v-bind for element attributes. The answer to your problem was simply to add a v-model to the iterated radio buttons.

PS: Your name value does not work, with what I have helped you with I think you should be able to get this fixed, *hint: v-bind*

```js
    new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    template:`<div>
        <div>{{selected_unit}}</div>
            <div class="radio" v-for="pricingUnit in pricing_units">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                    v-model="selected_unit" 
                    v-bind:value="pricingUnit.display" 
                    name="pricing[unconfirmed_units]" >
                        {{pricingUnit.display}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`,
    data: {
        selected_unit:'per_watt',
        pricing_units: [
            {short:'per_watt', display:'Per Watt'},
            {short:'flat_rate', display:'Flate Rate'}
        ]
    }
    })
```

Comment: It would help if you asked me a question more directly, but I think you're trying to have a radio button selected by default. If we change the value we are binding to the short property of each object we can make this work. In the example you just linked you still are not using v-model. I suggest you look over my solution and compare it to yours. Here is a working version with a default value: https://jsfiddle.net/Henkers/y4ear9xu/

Comment: thx - yeah, in our app we don't need v-model to update (it actually would cause a problem since in a modal overlay). thx for help